# content change dynamic with variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, textarea

Hi guys i have sending a message to customer mobile like this

```
$message="Your ticket is booked for ID='$id'";
```

So now my boss tell me that we need a provision to customize this message.may be like this

```
 $message="Your ticket  ID='$id' is booked,you are welcome";
```

They will change the message simultaneously.
So i add a part in admin to change that message using text area.But what i do with that variable `$id`? How i add variable to database and fetch that?

Comment: ..probably you need to edit the php file handling that message.

Comment: @MarinNedea like what editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save your message in database like this

```
$message="Your ticket  ID= ###id### is booked,you are welcome";
```

And while getting the data from database

```
$message = //message from db

str_replace("###id###", $id, $message);
```

Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: $message="Your ticket  ID= %s is booked,you are welcome";

and then use sprintf()?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use a placeholder for that. As input, you could for instance define a `%ID%` placeholder, and replace that dynamically when you retrieve the message from your database.

For example, when your boss enters the message `"Your ticket is booked for ID=%ID%"`, you replace `%ID%` with the real ID in your PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

```
$message="Your ticket  ID = {{ id }}is booked,you are welcome";
$message = str_replace("{{ id }}", $id, $message);
echo $message;
```

Here I suggesting the same as vaibhav but more visible format